# How to efficiently check if a table is empty?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In the program I'm currently writing there is a point where I need to check whether a table is empty or not. I currently just have a basic SQL execution statement that is

```
Count(asterisk) from Table
```

I then have a fetch method to grab this one row, put the `Count(asterisk)` into a parameter so I can check against it (Error if count(*) < 1 because this would mean the table is empty). On average, the `count(asterisk)` will return about 11,000 rows. Would something like this be more efficient?

```
 select count(*) 
 from (select top 1 * 
        from TABLE)
```

but I can not get this to work in Microsoft SQL Server

This would return 1 or 0 and I would be able to check against this in my programming language when the statement is executed and I fetch the count parameter to see whether the TABLE is empty or not.

Any comments, ideas, or concerns are welcome.

Comment: You shouldn't ever have to ask "would this be more efficient" - SQL Server gives you plenty of tools to evaluate query performance (execution plans, DMVs & DMOs, profiler traces, etc.) such that you can get a definitive answer from your own environment. Using data representative of your production environment, try your query several ways & choose the one that produces the best results.

Comment: Very new to Microsoft SQL server and not familiar with these tools. I will look more into the tools you mentioned. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You are looking for an indication if the table is empty. For that SQL has the EXISTS keyword.
If you are doing this inside a stored procedure use this pattern:

```
IF(NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.MyTable))
BEGIN
  RAISERROR('MyError',16,10);
END;
```

IF you get the indicator back to act accordingly inside the app, use this pattern:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.MyTable) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsEmpty;
```

While most of the other responses will produce the desired result too, they seem to obscure the intent.

Comment: Parentheses - () - around `NOT Exists ...` are not mandatory. This is right tool to check if a row exists in a table.

Comment: @Stoleg, you are correct that the `()` are not mandatory. It is just a pattern that I have adopted to always wrap the `IF` condition into `()` as most other languages require it.

Comment: It is a good practice to add TOP  1 in your exists statement. On very large tables you will return every record.

Comment: That is incorrect, @KeyOfJ. SQL Server will stop an EXITS query as soon as the first row is found, independent of a TOP clause being present or not.

Comment: @SebastianMeine Thanks, I always assumed that is why we were taught to add the TOP 1. 

"The EXISTS operator terminates the query processing immediately once it finds a row, therefore, you can leverage this feature of the EXISTS operator to improve the query performance."

Answer (score 12):

You could try something like this:

```
select count(1) where exists (select * from t)
```

Tested on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0490c/9/0)

Comment: +1 . . . I happen to like this method because it is standard SQL.

Comment: @Stoleg Because the requirement was to select 1 or 0, and `select 1` would return no rows if the table is empty.

Comment: @mustaccio my apologies! It does!

Answer (score 8):

Please, use top 1 when you checking for existence because without it you will have as many 'ones' as a number of records:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(select top 1 1 from Table)
BEGIN
  RAISERROR('Error',0,1);
END;
```

Comment: This seems redundant, yes? `IF NOT EXISTS` already stops after the first occurrence, so adding `TOP 1` is just unnecessary syntax.

Answer (score 4):

IF EXISTS can be used for check if a table is empty.

```
IF EXISTS (select * from YourTable)
SELECT 'Table is not empty'
ELSE
SELECT 'Table is empty'
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems like an odd way to get what you want.  Can you just use `HAVING` instead?

```
SELECT id, name FROM TABLE
GROUP BY id, name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to write about `EXISTS`, but Sebastian Meine got it faster. Although I would prefer using `EXISTS`, there is one more method.

```
SELECT rows 
FROM sys.partitions 
WHERE object_id = object_id('MyTableName') 
    AND partition_number = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Your variation is fine.  You just need an alias on the subquery:

```
 select count(*) 
 from (select top 1 * 
        from TABLE
      ) t
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon. I usually write queries in MS Access and did not know I had to make an alias on the subquery so this is very helpful.